# How to measure rendering time in Chrome 1000 times?

Tags: performance, google-chrome, profiling, rendering

I am working on a proof of concept and I need to measure the rendering time  of a simple website (just a HTML document and one CSS file) 1000 times in a browser. Is there a simple and straightforward tool for this?

I know there are some highly complicated tools with an enormous learning curve, but I don't have the whole week to tinker with it. I don't need anything else just the rendering time, exactly as Chrome's Performance tool displays it in milliseconds, then calculate an average.

If someone could tell me how to find the total rendering time of the page in the (quite enormous) JSON output of the Performance tool, I'd be happy with that. I can have a macro recorder clicking the Refresh button all night. Though I guess there's a way to get it done from the command prompt - any advice is appreciated on that too!

Answer (score 2):

The 'Audits' tab in Chrome's dev tools allows you to run a lighthouse performance audit, which will provide you some key metrics as defined by Google (such as time to interactive): https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/.

You can run it from the command line too, which should make it somewhat straightforward to repeat it as needed in your scenario and perhaps even integrate it as a test: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/#cli

Comment: Yeah, I found Lighthouse in the meantime, thanks :)